# Python pymysql INSERT INTO inserting empty values

Tags: python, sql, pymysql

I'm trying to insert some values in a table, and although the rows are being created, the values aren't being recorded. Here is my code:

```
for i in range(2,6):
    for team in ul[i]:
        name = team.string #string from html element
        print(name) #this works just fine, and prints the desired name
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO teams (Name) VALUES(name)")
conn.commit()
```

Now if I put `VALUES("Test String")` instead, it works, 30 rows are added (what I want), and all with the Name: "Test String".

Yet when I put in my `name` variable, the rows are added as well, but the column values are empty. The column I'm putting the strings in is `VARCHAR`. Is there something I don't know about how the SQL statement is interpreted in the case of Python string variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the SQL statement is a simple string and he `name` variable isn't being inserted into it.

Perhaps you could do something like this:

```
sql = """INSERT INTO teams (Name) VALUES({0})""".format(json.dumps(name))
cur.execute(sql)
```

I use `json.dumps(myVar)` to escape special characters, e.g. quotes, etc... that might break the SQL insert statement.

Sometimes it's helpful to print out the SQL statement and try to run it in a client (e.g. MySQL Workbench), in order to see what changes, if any, are necessary to generate syntactically correct statements.

Comment: This works, thanks! I found that the type of my `name` variable was `<class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>`, so that's probably why the query didn't recognize it

Comment: Considering that `name` is coming from a HTML form or something like that, you really should use query parameters for the insert. String formatting opens a chance for SQL injection.